# Unregistering manually deleted VirtualBox VMs

Tags: virtualbox

Removed my `VirtualBox VMs` folder without first deleting my VMs. [whoops!]

I've run `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*` and restarted. Reinstalled `virtualbox-5.0`.

```
$ VBoxManage --version
5.0.14r105127

$ VBoxManage list vms
"<inaccessible>" {8f192d64-6be3-4721-8601-af26cce18b4d}
"<inaccessible>" {85a69bcf-8a1b-421b-9c03-9c78b09aec9e}
"<inaccessible>" {d4810253-3159-4073-99ca-d1a2f56f10b2}

$ VBoxManage unregistervm {657cbfe1-8557-4181-a7bb-9d4919cafbae} --delete
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine with UUID {657cbfe1-8557-4181-a7bb-9d4919cafbae}
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(VMName).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 151 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

How do I start afresh?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can just manually edit my config file, i.e.: `VirtualBox.xml`

Answer (score -1):

Use `VBoxManage unregistervm Your_Id` for your three old ID's, similar to [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12205).

Comment: Tried that. See my question.